Как сделать 4 фона в css друг за другом
Мне нужно сделать 4 фона, они должны идти друг за другом. Два фона хорошо встают, но если я пытаюсь вставить третий, то по такому-же принципу ничего не получается. Вот что должно получится:
Вот сам код:
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: default;
  background-image: url(https:.jpg), url(https:.jpg), url(https:.jpg), (https:.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat, repeat-x, repeat;
}

при таком коде второй фон начинает повторятся.
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Если я ставлю no-repeat на второй фон, то все ломается.

А почему он не должен повторятся если вы сказали ему повторяться (repeat)?

И что значит «всё ломается»?

ну все фоны пропадают и тупо белый экран

если я ставлю repeat-x все точно также. Мне просто подсказали как с двумя фонами так сделать, а сам с 4 не могу додуматься

Нужен живой пример где-нибудь на codepen

https://codepen.io/deekfkjy-the-scripter/pen/zYVvJaq

если что, я пытаюсь повторить сайт

Тут всё ОЧЕНЬ плохо. Вёрстку надо переделать. Вам нужны отдельные блоки каждый со своим фоном, а не 4 фона на body. Нужно использовать нормальные теги для заголовоков и текста, не диватоз[https://doka.guide/html/div/#alyona-batickaya-sovetuet]. Не нужно разбивать фразы посередине ради переноса строк. В общем есть куда работать.
